# Python load variables into an array from file

Tags: python, arrays, reddit, praw

I'm making a reddit bot and I've made it store the comment ids in an array so it doesn't reply to the same comment twice, however if I close the program the array is cleared.

I'm looking for a way to keep the array, such as storing it in an external file and reading it, thanks!

Here's my code:

```
import praw
import time
import random
import pickle

#logging into the Reddit API
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="Random Number machine by /u/---")
print("Logging in...")
r.login(---,---, disable_warning=True)
print("Logged in.")


wordsToMatch = ["+randomnumber","+random number","+ randomnumber","+ random number"] #Words which the bot looks for.
cache = [] #If a comment ID is stored here, the bot will not reply back to the same post.

def run_bot():
    print("Start of new loop.")
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(---) #Decides which sub-reddit to search for comments.
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=100) #Grabbing comments...
    print(cache)

    for comment in comments:
        comment_text = comment.body.lower() #Stores the comment in a variable and lowers it.
        isMatch = any(string in comment_text for string in wordsToMatch) #If the bot matches a comment with the wordsToMatch array.

        if comment.id not in cache and isMatch: #If a comment is found and the ID isn't in the cache.
            print("Comment found: {}".format(comment.id)) #Prints the following line to console, develepors see this only.
            #comment.reply("Hey, I'm working!")
            #cache.append(comment.id)
while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: write the list to a file with `json.dumps`

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called [*serialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  You can use [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`yaml`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) or even [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).  They all have very similar APIs:

```
import json

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

with open("/tmp/foo.json", "w") as fd:
    json.dump(a, fd)

with open("/tmp/foo.json") as fd:
    b = json.load(fd)

assert b == a
```

foo.json:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.json
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`json` and `yaml` only work with basic types like strings, numbers, lists, and dictionaries.  Pickle has more flexibility allowing you to serialize more complex types like classes.  `json` is generally used for communication between programs, while `yaml` tends to be used when the input is needed to be edited/read by humans as well.

For your case, you probably want `json`.  If you want to make it pretty, there are options to the `json` library to indent the output.